# xv6 stack dynamic memory management

Tags: c, memory-management, xv6

I'm trying to implement a new dynamic memory logic (malloc/free) in xv6, which has the following behavior.
The main point is that memory blocks will follow LIFO concept, meaning that free() can only free the last block allocated in memory.

1. when malloc() is called, mem-manager will check if there's enough memory for the process. if so, it marks a new block and returns the address. if not - it will ask for a new page from os (using sbrk) and then put the new block.
2. free() will "pop" the last allocated block. if after the action a whole page is freed, it calls sbrk with (-PGZISE) i.e release the last page. but that's not relevant for now since my bug is in the malloc.

Here is my implentation.
I'm trying to hold a data-structure of a header that is part of each block, containing it's size and pointer to the previous block start.

My test includes simply 100 calls to malloc(512)

for some reason I'm getting usertrap() error in the 10th call, no matter what I do.
would appreciate any help to get this code working. I'm sure I'm really close.

```
#define PGSIZE 4096 // bytes per page
#define PGSHIFT 12  // bits of offset within a page

#define PGROUNDUP(sz) (((sz) + PGSIZE - 1) & ~(PGSIZE - 1))
#define PGROUNDDOWN(a) (((a)) & ~(PGSIZE - 1))

typedef unsigned long uint64;

struct header
{
    uint len;
    struct header *prev;
    char* end;
};

struct header base;
struct header *top = &base;

void *ustack_malloc(uint len)
{

    if (len > USTACK_MAC_OP_SIZE)
        return 0; // we don't allow allocating more than 512bytes

    struct header *nb = (struct header *)(top->end);  // New Block starts from the end of the prev
    nb = (struct header *)((uint64)top + (uint64)top->len);   // new block starts from where the current top ends
    printf("nb address: %p\n", nb);
    // calculating if we have enough mem, or should get a new page. also, nb should be like that:
    //  -------MEM----|--------|---nb----|----------------||
    //                ^        ^                       ^
    //                top      top+len                  PAGEROUNDUP(top)
    if (top == &base || PGROUNDUP((uint64)top->end) - ((uint64)top->end) < len+sizeof(struct header))
    {
        printf("allocating more place!\n");
        if (sbrk(PGSIZE) == 0)
        {             // QUESTION is this the right calling?
            return 0; // notify failed
        }
    }

    // adding nb to the top of the stack and updating top]
    nb->len = len;
    nb->prev = top;
    nb->end = (char*)(nb+len+sizeof(struct header)+1);
    top = nb;
    // now mem should look like this:
    //  -------MEM----|---nb---|
    //                ^        ^
    //                top      top+len
    return (void *)((uint64)&top + (uint64)sizeof(struct header)); // should divide sizeof by 8???
}
```

The error is as follows. I understands it's because of illegal access to memory, but I do have enough memory!

```
usertrap(): unexpected scause 0x000000000000000f pid=3
            sepc=0x00000000000008f2 stval=0x0000000000002030
```

Thank you